# Addressing email while sending resume

Tags: cover-letter

There's a job posting which specifically mentions that resumes should be sent to talent specialist and a generic email is given like recruitment@xyz.com.

I am confused with whom should I address the cover letter. I've searched the company's site which mentions of a director, national director &  COO in the recruitment team and mentions there email ids and phone numbers too.

Should I use "Dear Hiring Manager" or "Talent Specialist" or start with the name of any one of these three mentioned on the company's website. Any suggestions ??

Also who will be more senior a director or national director ? I think it should be the Director.

Answer (score 2):

They use a generic email address like "recruitment@xyz.com" so they can send it to a shared inbox and anyone on the team can process it.

In your situation I wouldn't try to guess; I would start my email with

> Hello,
>
> <body of email here>

In short, don't over think this.